# PHP/Codeigniter sessions getting destroyed

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am working on a web app at the moment, the users logs in a session is created and logged to the database.

What is occurring is that a user will get randomly get logged out, through no option of their own. The backstory is that this is generally happening to users who are sharing an account (not the best thing but the nature of the app, means it needs to be allowable).

Could this be the reason for the random logouts? Or is something deeper in CI and storing sessions in the database? I also read that doing a lot of AJAX requests close together can cause the SESSION ID to change, and the could then overwrite the database record and log the user out. Again is this a possibility? I think this one is less so as I have written a patch to stop this happening.

SESSION CONFIG:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'app';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['sess_use_multisessions'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_multisession_expiration'] = 10;
```

Comment: Why dont you share some of your code? Its always preferable to share your code to get the maximum response on your question

Comment: What do you want to see? The login code that creates the SESSION?

Comment: What happens if you open an incognito session and try login with the same account?

Comment: If you can share the handling of incognito session....

Comment: check `session_expiration` in config file..make sure its value is `0`. Do share the session config variables from config file

Comment: `multi_sessions` seems new to me.. never saw them in CI Docs..have u extended Session Library ?

Comment: Yes to allow for quick database and ajax calls that would otherwise overwrite and log. I'm wondering if just turning sess_use_database to FALSE will solve my problem

Comment: i use ajax calls too but never faced any session destroying issue..try removing the multisession code & check again

Comment: This is a known issue and is usually related to AJAX calls that are being sent from the frontend. The problem is related to the sess_time_to_update (correct me if im wrong). I would recommend using a different session manager with CI, I would check the CI forums for one of these.

Comment: I've had similar problems with CI when using AJAX extensively. I found the only fix was to set $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 7200 * 2; Not optimal but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, for my previous answer. I was wrong. I am not sure about this two config settings, not able to find in the CI manual also.
$config['sess_use_multisessions'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_multisession_expiration'] = 10;

But, this won't make any problem.

Please try by making $config['sess_match_useragent'] to TRUE.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I have modified my answer. Please check my edited answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing your sessions in the DB (`ci_sessions` table) ? Try changing the field type of `user_agent` to `mediumtext`. It's `varchar255` by default and some user agent strings are longer, and this can cause logouts.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my config setting `$config['sess_time_to_update']    = 300;` to `$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 8400;` it is behaving better than previous, By doing this u may have security issue as session will take much time to update and till update session id will remain same.

More I am also searching a perfect solution for this, I have also worked for ajax like many other threads on stackoverflow explained, but that does not work for me.

In the DB (`ci_sessions table`) i have also changed the field type of `user_agent` to `text`, it also does not work for me.